# Post meta is not accessible within save_post hook

Tags: custom-post-types, save-post

I am using this code to update post meta but it is not working.

```
function run_when_job_published( $post_id, $post, $update){
   $post_meta = get_post_meta($post_id);
}
add_action('save_post_jobs', 'run_when_job_published', 10, 3);
```

But here in this function `$post_meta` is returning an empty array.
Actually I want to update one of the meta field during post insertion but I think it is not possible with this hook. I have also tried `publish_post` hook but in my scenario it is not working.
Any suggestion will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: that looks to be right.  remove `global $post` and see if the `$post` variable being passed in is what you're expecting it to be. same with the `$post_id` variable

Comment: Yes I am getting correct values from "$post" and "$post_id" but not able to get data from post meta.

Comment: Meta data hasn’t been saved yet when the action fires, try looking in $_POST

Comment: @Milo for your suggestion. I will try this.

Comment: i think this is action problem

Comment: please try this add_action('save_post', 'run_when_job_published', 10, 3);